# Need to downgrade/reinstall pip due to upgrade breaking all functionality

Tags: amazon-ec2, pip

On my Amazon EC2 instance, I upgraded pip on a whim, and now nearly every command I try to run with it returns an error like this:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Now I can't really do anything to fix it from within pip. I tried running `pip uninstall pip` just to see if I would get lucky, and it looked like it was going to work, but then it gave the same error. I'm at about a 3 out of 10 on my Linux familiarity. EC2 uses the yum package manager, and trying `yum remove pip` did not find the package.

Comment: `yum remove python-pip`

Comment: You can downgrade if you know the specific version of pip you need: `pip install --upgrade pip==8.1.2`

Answer (score 2):

**try this**

```
sudo python -m pip install --force-reinstall pip==8.1.1
```

Comment: Why? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it